# Best method to get objects from a BlockingQueue in a concurrent program?

Tags: java, concurrency

What is the best method to get objects out of a BlockingQueue, in a concurrent program, without hitting a race condition?  I'm currently doing the following and I'm not convinced it is the best method:

```
BlockingQueue<Violation> vQueue;
/* 
in the constructor I pass in a BlockingQueue object 
full of violations that need to be processed - cut out for brevity
*/

Violation v;
while ( ( v = vQueue.poll(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) ) != null ) {
    // do stuff with the violation
}
```

I have yet to hit a race condition... but, I'm none too sure if this is truly safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Producer implements Runnable {
   private final BlockingQueue queue;
   Producer(BlockingQueue q) { queue = q; }
   public void run() {
     try {
       while (true) { queue.put(produce()); }
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... handle ...}
   }
   Object produce() { ... }
 }

 class Consumer implements Runnable {
   private final BlockingQueue queue;
   Consumer(BlockingQueue q) { queue = q; }
   public void run() {
     try {
       while (true) { consume(queue.take()); }
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... handle ...}
   }
   void consume(Object x) { ... }
 }

 class Setup {
   void main() {
     BlockingQueue q = new SomeQueueImplementation();
     Producer p = new Producer(q);
     Consumer c1 = new Consumer(q);
     Consumer c2 = new Consumer(q);
     new Thread(p).start();
     new Thread(c1).start();
     new Thread(c2).start();
   }
 }
```

This example was taken from the [JDK 1.6 docs of `BlockingQueue`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). So You can see that you are doing it the right way. Here's the quote which tells you that it have to work:

> Memory consistency effects: As with
>   other concurrent collections, actions
>   in a thread prior to placing an object
>   into a BlockingQueue happen-before
>   actions subsequent to the access or
>   removal of that element from the
>   BlockingQueue in another thread.