# C# thread pool limiting threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-2.0, threadpool

Alright...I've given the site a fair search and have read over many posts about this topic. I found this question: [Code for a simple thread pool in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435668/code-for-a-simple-thread-pool-in-c) especially helpful.

However, as it always seems, what I need varies slightly.

I have looked over the MSDN example and adapted it to my needs somewhat. The example I refer to is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(VS.80,printer).aspx

My issue is this. I have a fairly simple set of code that loads a web page via the `HttpWebRequest` and `WebResponse` classes and reads the results via a `Stream`. I fire off this method in a thread as it will need to executed many times. The method itself is pretty short, but the number of times it needs to be fired (with varied data for each time) varies. It can be anywhere from 1 to 200.

Everything I've read seems to indicate the `ThreadPool` class being the prime candidate. Here is what things get tricky. I might need to fire off this thing say 100 times, but I can only have 3 threads at most running (for this particular task).

I've tried setting the `MaxThreads` on the `ThreadPool` via:

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(3, 3);
```

I'm not entirely convinced this approach is working. Furthermore, I don't want to clobber other web sites or programs running on the system this will be running on. So, by limiting the # of threads on the `ThreadPool`, can I be certain that this pertains to my code and my threads only?

The MSDN example uses the event drive approach and calls `WaitHandle.WaitAll(doneEvents);` which is how I'm doing this.

So the heart of my question is, how does one ensure or specify a maximum number of threads that can be run for their code, but have the code keep running more threads as the previous ones finish up until some arbitrary point? Am I tackling this the right way?

---

Okay, I've added a semaphore approach and completely removed the `ThreadPool` code. It seems simple enough. I got my info from: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx

It's this example that showed me how:

> A `Semaphore` with a capacity of one is similar to a `Mutex` or `lock`, except that the `Semaphore` has no "owner" – it's thread-agnostic. Any thread can call `Release` on a `Semaphore`, while with `Mutex` and `lock`, only the thread that obtained the resource can release it.
>
> In this following example, ten threads execute a loop with a `Sleep` statement in the middle. A `Semaphore` ensures that not more than three threads can execute that `Sleep` statement at once:
>
> ```
> class SemaphoreTest
> {
>     static Semaphore s = new Semaphore(3, 3);  // Available=3; Capacity=3
>
>     static void Main()
>     {
>         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
>             new Thread(Go).Start();
>     }
>
>     static void Go()
>     {
>         while (true)
>         {
>             s.WaitOne();
>     
>             Thread.Sleep(100);   // Only 3 threads can get here at once
>     
>             s.Release();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Note: if you are limiting this to "3" just so you don't overwhelm the machine running your app, I'd make sure this is a problem first. The threadpool is supposed to manage this for you. On the other hand, if you don't want to overwhelm some other resource, then read on!

---

You can't manage the size of the threadpool (or really much of anything about it).

In this case, I'd use a semaphore to manage access to your resource. In your case, your resource is running the web scrape, or calculating some report, etc.

To do this, in your static class, create a semaphore object:

```
System.Threading.Semaphore S = new System.Threading.Semaphore(3, 3);
```

Then, in each thread, you do this:

```
System.Threading.Semaphore S = new System.Threading.Semaphore(3, 3);

try
{
    // wait your turn (decrement)
    S.WaitOne();
    // do your thing
}

finally {
    // release so others can go (increment)
    S.Release();
}
```

Each thread will block on the S.WaitOne() until it is given the signal to proceed. Once S has been decremented 3 times, all threads will block until one of them increments the counter.

This solution isn't perfect.

---

If you want something a little cleaner, and more efficient, I'd recommend going with a BlockingQueue approach wherein you enqueue the work you want performed into a global Blocking Queue object.

Meanwhile, you have three threads (which you created--not in the threadpool), popping work out of the queue to perform. This isn't that tricky to setup and is very fast and simple.

Examples:

- [Best threading queue example / best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346268/best-threading-queue-example-best-practice)
- [Best method to get objects from a BlockingQueue in a concurrent program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950/best-method-to-get-objects-from-a-blockingqueue-in-a-concurrent-program)

Comment: Micheal, can you elaborate a bit more on the Semaphore example? This is the first I've read/heard of them.

Comment: Jason: I definitely recommend the second approach (blocking queue/producer-consumer)--it's much easier IMO. For more on Semaphores, though, read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx

Comment: Shouldn't it be Semaphore(3,3), WaitOne decrements and Release increments?

Comment: @Bjarke Ebert: thanks for the correction: I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

It's a static class like any other, which means that anything you do with it affects every other thread in the current process. It doesn't affect other processes.

I consider this one of the larger design flaws in .NET, however. Who came up with the brilliant idea of making the thread pool *static*? As your example shows, we often want a thread pool dedicated to *our* task, without having it interfere with unrelated tasks elsewhere in the system.

Comment: The thread pool is meant to be used process-wide. What you're looking for is a task manager that can be instatiated on demand. If you look at the ParallelLINQ and Task Parallel Library from Microsoft (will be rolled into .NET 4), it has what you're looking for.

Comment: That doesn't mean it's not a design flaw. They should have allowed it to be instantiated on demand from day 1. Of course, there's nothing to stop them from also providing a static instance of this class, if they want to explicitly support "process-wide" tasks. But I'm glad .NET4 will finally fix it.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense, when you realize that the number of available processors/cores is also rather static. And those are shared with all other processes, tasks and threads anyway. So what's the point of having two threadpools in one application compete with each other for the same set of CPU resources?

Comment: Control. Say you have four cores, and two groups of tasks which must never completely block out each others. Then you could make two thread pools with three threads each. My question is why *not* allow it. What is the point in explicitly preventing it?

Comment: You can easily create your own custom threadpool, if you don't want to use the static one.

Comment: @Judah - I believe the Parallel library by default uses ThreadPool under the covers, so if a static ThreadPool is a problem without the Parallel library, it will still be a problem _with_ the Parallel library.